# Finding a word in a list next to an input word in python

Tags: python

I want to find the string that comes after a string from a list. So If the input word is: “Can”, I want to find the word that is displayed after the word “can in the list.

How do I code this in python?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question-answering service, and much of the time those answers involve writing code. It's no more complicated than that. No, it's not specifically a code-writing service because you can't ask for any arbitrary code and expect to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try in this way. I assumed `arr` is list of strings. `word` is the input for the use

```
arr = ['hello','how','can','I','help']
word = input("Enter the word")
for i in range(len(arr)-1):
    if arr[i]==word:
        print(arr[i+1])
```

If the input word is not present in the array, it prints nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach which handles index out of range as well when the input word is last element in the list:

```
arr = ['hello', 'world', 'how', 'can', 'i', 'help',  'you']
word = input("Enter the word: ")
if word.lower() not in arr:
    print (f'The word {word} does not exists in the list')
else:
    try:
        index = arr.index(word.lower())
        print (f'Next word: {arr[index+1]}')
    except IndexError:
        print (f'No word exists after {word}')
```

Some of the outputs:

```
Enter the word: hellow
The word hellow does not exists in the list

Enter the word: world
Next word: how

Enter the word: you
No word exists after you
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I understand how to code it now. Thanks